# Can a mute person do teshuva?

Tags: rambam, repentance-teshuvah, speech-talking, handicap-disabled-impair

The **Rambam** in [Hilchos Teshuvah 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) tells us that saying *vidui* (confessing) is an integral part of the teshuva process:

> כָּל מִצְוֹת שֶׁבַּתּוֹרָה בֵּין עֲשֵׂה בֵּין לֹא תַּעֲשֶׂה אִם עָבַר אָדָם עַל אַחַת מֵהֶן בֵּין בְּזָדוֹן בֵּין בִּשְׁגָגָה כְּשֶׁיַּעֲשֶׂה תְּשׁוּבָה וְיָשׁוּב מֵחֶטְאוֹ **חַיָּב לְהִתְוַדּוֹת** לִפְנֵי הָאֵל בָּרוּךְ הוּא שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (במדבר ה ו) "אִישׁ אוֹ אִשָּׁה כִּי יַעֲשׂוּ" וְגוֹ' (במדבר ה ז) "וְהִתְוַדּוּ אֶת חַטָּאתָם אֲשֶׁר עָשׂוּ" **זֶה וִדּוּי דְּבָרִים. וִדּוּי זֶה מִצְוַת עֲשֵׂה. כֵּיצַד מִתְוַדִּין. אוֹמֵר אָנָּא הַשֵּׁם חָטָאתִי עָוִיתִי פָּשַׁעְתִּי לְפָנֶיךָ וְעָשִׂיתִי כָּךְ וְכָךְ וַהֲרֵי נִחַמְתִּי וּבֹשְׁתִּי בְּמַעֲשַׂי וּלְעוֹלָם אֵינִי חוֹזֵר לְדָבָר זֶה. וְזֶהוּ עִקָּרוֹ שֶׁל וִדּוּי.** וְכָל הַמַּרְבֶּה לְהִתְוַדּוֹת וּמַאֲרִיךְ בְּעִנְיָן זֶה הֲרֵי זֶה מְשֻׁבָּח וְכֵוּ'
>
> All the commandments of the Torah, whether mandatory or prohibitive, if a person violates any one of them, either on purpose or by accident, when he repents and returns from his sinful ways, **he is obligated to confess** before Hashem, as it is said: "When a man or woman shall commit any sin..… Then they shall confess their sin which they have done (Num. 5.6–7), **which is a confession of words. Such confession is a positive commandment. How is the verbal confession made? The sinner says: "I beseech Thee, O Great Name! I have sinned; I have been obstinate; I have committed profanity against Thee, particularly in doing thus and such. Now, behold! I have repented and am ashamed of my actions; forever will I not relapse into this thing again." This is the essence form of *teshuvah*;** but whosoever elaborates in confessing and extends this subject is, indeed, praise-worthy.

With this in mind (and since he can't verbalize it) is it possible for a mute person to do teshuva?

Comment: Where do you see in Rambam that if one doesn’t confess he hasn’t performed teshuvah. All he says in the passage you quote is that when one does teshuvah, he is obligated to confess.

Comment: @JoelK why would one be obligated to confess then? It would appear that verbally confessing is an integral part of doing teshuva

Comment: To modify Yevamos 14:1, כשם שהוא חוטא ברמיזה, כך הוא שב ברמיזה.

Comment: What would a Cheresh be doing Teshuvah for? Isn't he exempted from all Mitzvos anyways? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53164/whats-the-source-that-a-cheresh-shoteh-and-kattan-are-free-from-mitzvos

Comment: @Salmononius2 someone mute isn't a cheresh. A Cheresh is אינו שומע ואינו מדבר. A mute is שומע ואינו מדבר

Comment: @Meir ‘s comment is underrated. *Pilpulim* are cute, some might even think they’re fun but, WADR, the question is silly. A mute would be accountable for sinning but deprived of the opportunity to repent because he can’t speak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *sefer* [**LeDofkei BaTeshuva**](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=601485&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0) by **Rabbi Uri Teegar** on **Rambam**'s *Hilchos Teshuva* 1:1, in *Biurim* *s.v.* על לשון כל ישראל (near § 65, it's too far to see for free on Otzar HaChochma) brings the **Sefer HaChinuch** [§ 364](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.364.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), who explains the reasons for *vidui* (verbal confession): (1) expressing one's sins reveals one's thoughts and beliefs, such that it's clear they don't think their sin went unnoticed by Hashem. As well, (2) through expressing it they'll regret their actions more and will refrain from transgressing again. Although a person can have regret even without verbalizing it, explicit *vidui* will make a stronger impression.

The former brings from the *sefer* **Hirhurei Teshuvah** *ad. loc.* § 5 that according to the first reason of the **Chinuch**, someone who is mute, their lack of verbalizing the *vidui* shouldn't detract from their thoughts. It's just that someone who could speak and doesn't will be lacking.

**LeDofkei BaTeshuva** suggests that even according to the second reason, since the mute person can't speak, we shouldn't say that verbalizing in order to make an impression is מעכב/inhibitive.

He also brings ([*Sha'ar HaTziyun*](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=601485&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0&pagenum=31) ad. loc. § 143, 144, 146, 150 - 153, 156) those who say a person's atonement is completely dependent on verbal expression of *vidui*, and without it their *teshuva* wasn't effective (**Minchas Chinuch** 364:1). However, if they were *shogeg*/accidentally negligent or *oness*/without fault, their *teshuva* should be effective (**Derech HaMelech** *ad. loc. peirush he'aruch* § 2, not like the **Minchas Chinuch**. **Rav Chaim Kanievsky** *shlita* in the margin comments: "ודאי"). Based on this, it would seem someone who is mute, who is clearly an *oness*, would be fine.

However, the person needs to think the entire *vidui* text as they would have verbally (**LeTeshuvas HaShana** p. 106. **Rav Chaim Kanievsky** in the margin comments: "יפה").

Some go further that if any person performed *teshuva* in their heart and didn't verbally express *vidui*, it's still considered *teshuva* (**Yad Ketana** *ad. loc.* § 6. **Minchas Chinuch** *loc. cit.* seems to concur in the end), and they receive atonement (**Shu"t Beis Avi** 2:53). It's just that they didn't fulfill the *mitzvah* of *vidui*.

Others say that *teshuva* and *vidui* of the heart is enough, (**Shu"t Lev Chaim** 1:10, 3:136. **Beis Elokim** *Sha'ar HaTefilah* Chapter 12. **Imros Tehoros** Chapter 5), just it's better to express *vidui* verbally.

Finally, there are those who say that if a person's *teshuva* was sincere and complete, then the *vidui* isn't inhibitive (**Shu"t Mishneh Sachir** *Orach Chaim* 162:1). As Micha Berger pointed out, immediately once a person thinks in *teshuva* they considered like they're completely righteous, regardless of their atonement status (**Minchas Chinuch** *loc. cit.* **Koach HaTeshuva** 11:2 points out that this is already explicit in **Ohr Zaruah** 1:112).

**Note:** The above author and Rav Chaim Kanievsky both stressed that their presentations of the different opinions are entirely their own and should not be relied upon. A person should always consult their local Orthodox Rabbi.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the Rambam again, he actually says something more radical. "כְּשֶׁיַּעֲשֶׂה תְּשׁוּבָה וְיָשׁוּב מֵחֶטְאוֹ חַיָּב לְהִתְוַדּוֹת -- ... when he does teshuvah, he is obligated to confess..."

The mitzvah is vidui (the confession), teshuvah is the context in which vidui would be said.

There is a dispute among acharonim as to whether the Rambam counts among the 613 mitzvos anything that is purely thought. This is part of a wider question about how we can be commanded to think or feel a certain way. The free will involved is certainly different; in the moment, we have very little control over what we believe or feel. It takes weeks to years of preliminary work to be in the right place in the moment.

In either case, Briskers believe that the Rambam does not count mitzvos of thought. R YB Soloveitchik in particular points to this Rambam as one example where he recasts the "maaseh mitzvah" to be an action, saying vidui, even though the chalos, the state-change we intend the mitzvah to cause, is in the heart.

So, it would seem to me that a deaf person cannot do the mitzvah of vidui.

As to whether they can do teshuvah...

Many a Shabbos Shuvah sermon invokes the case of a man who says "Behold you are wedded to me on the condition that I am righteous." The gemara rules ([Qiddushin 49b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.49b.4)) that even if he was [until then] a rasha gamar (totally wicked person), the marriage is binding. Because he could have had hirhurei teshuvah -- thoughts of repentance. And if so, the condition would be met.

(By which the gemara means means, binding enough to require a gett. If they want to remain married, we would still require a second wedding, because maybe he didn't have that thought. The whole thing is in a safeiq [maybe] state.)

The Alter of Slabodka, and those many rabbis in their sermons, note that even a thought of teshuvah can successfully clean the slate of even the most wicked.

So, it would seem that as long as a person can think, they can do teshuvah.